# Drawing a bootstrap sample from a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: numpy, pandas

I would like to draw a bootstrap sample of a `pandas.DataFrame` as efficiently as possible. Using the builtin `iloc` together with a list of integers seems to be slow:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
# Generate some data
n = 5000
values = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 5))
# Construct a pandas.DataFrame
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df = pandas.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
# Bootstrap
%timeit df.iloc[np.random.randint(n, size=n)]
# Out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop
```

Indexing the `numpy` array is of course much faster:

```
%timeit values[np.random.randint(n, size=n)]
# Out: 10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop
```

But even extracting the values, sampling the `numpy` array, and constructing a new `pandas.DataFrame` is faster:

```
%timeit pandas.DataFrame(df.values[np.random.randint(n, size=n)], columns=columns)
# Out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 302 µs per loop
```

@JohnE suggested `sample` which is unfortunately even slower:

```
%timeit df.sample(n, replace=True)
# Out: 100 loops, best of 3: 5.14 ms per loop
```

@firelynx suggested `merge`:

```
%timeit df.merge(pandas.DataFrame(index=np.random.randint(n, size=n)), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')
# Out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

Does anyone have an idea why `iloc` is so slow and/or whether there are better alternatives than extracting the values, sampling and then constructing a new `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: `sample()`?  New as of version 0.16.1.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sample

Comment: I added your suggestion. Unfortunately, that's even slower.

Comment: @JohnE, thanks for the clarification that a significant amount of time is spent in `np.random.randint`.

Comment: what is `columns`? You don't define it in your code. Need it to reproduce your tests.

Comment: @firelynx, sorry, someone modified my original post. I performed a rollback.

Comment: readers here may find [bootstrapped](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bootstrapped/0.0.1) handy - package for bootstrapped confidence intervals on arbitrary evaluation metrics.

Answer (score 7):

The merge method in pandas is fairly optimized, so I tried my luck with it and it gave me a significant speed increase. Given my machine is a bit slower than yours, I'm also using pandas 0.15.2 Things may be a bit different.

```
%timeit df.iloc[np.random.randint(n, size=n)]
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.41 ms per loop

randlist = pandas.DataFrame(index=np.random.randint(n, size=n))
%timeit df.merge(randlist, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop

%timeit df.merge(pandas.DataFrame(index=np.random.randint(n, size=n)), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## Indexing Speeds

Boolean Indexing tested to be slightly faster for me:

#### Boolean Indexing

```
%timeit -n10000 df[np.random.randint(2, size=n).astype(bool)]
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop
```

#### `numpy` sampling & re`DataFrame`ing

```
%timeit -n10000 pandas.DataFrame(df.values[np.random.randint(n, size=n)], columns=columns)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 380 µs per loop
```

Comment: The problem here is that boolean indexing is without-replacement whereas the sampling should be with-replacement.